# Bootstrap Toast won't show on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, toast

Using Bootstrap 5, I have the following Toast message placed at the end of my HTML file:

```
<div class="toast-container position-absolute p-3 top-0 end-0"
    style="width: 150px;">

    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive"
        aria-atomic="true" id="toast">
        <div class="toast-body rounded-3 text-center" id="toastsavedbody">
            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="toastmessage">Saved</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

During "body onload="init()"", I can call this toast:

```
function init(){
    $('#toast').toast({delay: 2000});
    $('#toast').toast('show');
}
```

And the Toast shows as expected.

For testing, I added a button to my page:

```
<body onload="init()">
...
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="cancel" onclick="cancel()">
...
</body>
```

This references a function in mypage.js:

```
function cancel(){
    $('#toast').toast('show');
}
```

Upon clicking on the button, I get the error: TypeError: $(...).toast is not a function

My scripts are referenced in the [head] in the following order:

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/mypage.js"></script>
```

I can't figure out why it works in the init() function called from the body onload but not from the button's function. What could change between onload and button's function that would cause the "toast" function to not be recognized?

Comment: How and where do you call cancel

Comment: @VojinPurić, cancel is just the onclick function of a button I repurposed to test the toast: <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="cancel" onclick="cancel()">

Comment: Where have you written definition for `cancel()`

Comment: @VojinPurić I added detail regarding the cancel() function.